# Applying unique() to each element in list

Tags: r, list, unique

I have a list with several elements of different length.

```
mylist <- list(one=c("A","B","B"), two=c("A","A","B"), three=c("X","X","Y"))
```

and I want to select the elements with a particular set of unique values, say elements `one` and `two`, both of which have unique values `"A","B"`.

I have tried

```
cond <- sapply(mylist, function(x) unique(x)==c("A","B"))
mylist[cond]
```

but this does not seem to work.

Comment: If you look at `cond` you'll see something is up. Then see what `unique(c("A","A","B")) == c("A","B")` - **two** `TRUE` values. R compares each element and returns true/false for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly what you need. If so, this will do:

```
mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,function(x) x[all(c("A","B") %in% unique(x))])

mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,function(x) x[all(c("A","B") == unique(x))])
```

These ones are essentially the same, if you remove the `all` function you can also return subsets of your values.

You can also use a simple `if` condition (or `ifelse` when needed), if you don't like the indexing:

```
lapply(mylist,function(x) if(all(c("A","B") == unique(x))) x)

mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,function(x) if(all(c("A","B") %in% unique(x))) x)
```

---

#### EDIT:

Based on your last comment, I think this robust solution is working best for the possible variation in your data:

```
mylist <- list(one=c("A","B","B"), two=c("A","A","B"), three=c("X","X","Y"),four=c("A","B","X"))

mylist2 <- lapply(mylist,function(x) if(all(unique(x) %in% c("A","B")) & all(c("A","B") %in% unique(x))) x)
```

I ditched the `==` versions, because they can't handle differing number of elements for comparison. Also I added a second condition to the `if` statement. Now it will discard the cases where the unique values contain other additional elements than the ones you're looking for.

Comment: The first one works also in a more complicated setting but the second one lists elements which have only part of the condition fulfilled — try e.g.  adding element `four=c("A","X","X")` to the list. Is there a way to keep it from showing the elements that do not meet the condition?

Comment: Alright, now it makes sense, thanks. However, with all approaches `mylist2` has the same length as `mylist` where some elements equal `NULL` or `character(0)`. Indexing would be great but I don't see it.

Comment: if your combination isn't found, no value will be returned for the respective entry in `mylist2`. But the entry is still there (but empty), hence the same `length`. Depending on how your real problem looks like and what your ultimate goal is, these empty elements will be removed by next steps or can be filtered easily with a little function like `mylist2[lapply(mylist2,length)>0]`. As for indexing, I meant returning the values which are occurring. Is that what you need?

Comment: Got it! It's close. I just noticed that it also includes elements with the stated unique values _and more_ — e.g. `four=c("A","B","X")`. Is there a way to restrict the elements to those with only the unique values stated?

Comment: I edited my solution. Please note that the previous solution isn't working properly for the updated problem. So please refer only to the most recent code.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to use `setdiff`,

```
Filter(length, lapply(mylist, function(i) i[length(setdiff(unique(i), c('A', 'B'))) == 0]))
#$one
#[1] "A" "B" "B"

#$two
#[1] "A" "A" "B"
```